# error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

Tags: mysql

I'm running on an Ubuntu 19.04 distro and have a Dockerfile which when we reach step 7;

```
Step 7/11 : RUN (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &); sleep 5; mysqladmin -u root -proot create wordpress
```

we get;

```
2019-10-09T12:18:34.365421Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

Looking at the error message: `mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.`

```
cookie@cookie-K501UX:~/code/docker$ ls -la /var/run/mysqld
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql  100 Oct  9 13:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 root  root  1060 Oct  9 13:10 ..
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql    6 Oct  9 13:10 mysqld.pid
srwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql    0 Oct  9 13:10 mysqld.sock
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql    6 Oct  9 13:10 mysqld.sock.lock
```

it does. And `Check that mysqld is running`

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-10-09 13:26:21 BST; 8min ago
```

it is. If the socket file exists and the MySQL daemon is running - what's the problem?

Comment: can you share the dockerfile , or only part of docker file from step 1 to 7 .

Comment: Original `Dockerfile` was from here: `https://github.com/how2dock/docbook/blob/master/ch01/supervisor/Dockerfile`

Comment: It just occurred to me that changing parameters for the Dockerfile breaks stuff - _new to Docker_. In my case, `Ubuntu 19.04` and `mysql` is no bueno. Rather it should be more like `Ubuntu 19.04` and `mariadb`. I've answered my own question essentially.

Comment: I think the original repo is out-of-date slightly. I'll try to find an up-to-date `Dockerfile` config for a modern Wordpress install and post my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are waiting for 5 secs , and may be your need 6 secs  or more

Before running `mysqladmin create wordpress`   you must check if  MYSQL is ready .

So you can use a loop with `mysqladmin ping` .

So the `RUN` command can be

```
RUN (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &); \
     while( ! mysqladmin ping ) ;do  sleep 1 ; date ; done ; \
     mysqladmin -u root -proot create wordpress
```

Comment: Great. I'll take a look at that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For an up-to-date `Dockerfile` which will compile see:

```
FROM ubuntu:19.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
 apache2 \
 php7.2 \
 php7.2-mysql \
 supervisor \
 wget

RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root' | debconf-set-selections && \
echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root' | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get install -qqy mariadb-server

RUN wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && \
 tar xzvf latest.tar.gz && \
 cp -R ./wordpress/* /var/www/html && \
 rm /var/www/html/index.html

RUN (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &); sleep 5; mysqladmin -u root -proot create wordpress

COPY wp-config.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```